# Building a workflow with dynamic input without using deprecated dynamic API

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'd like to make a workflow which downloads the list of some FASTQ files from the remote server, checks md5 and runs some post-processing, e.g. aligning.

I understand how to implement this using two workflows:

1. first download fastq files list file, e.g. `md5` file.
2. read the `md5` file content and create corresponding targets in `all` rule for desired resulting files.

I'd like to do this in a single workflow. The incorrect workflow below shows the idea what I'd like to achieve.

- in `all` rule `input:` section I don't know `{sample}` values before `md5` file is download and parsed
- I've tried to play with dynamic, checkpoints and subforkflows, but failed to achieve the desired result. As for `dynamic` I've managed only to implement this workflow only for dynamic("fastq/{sample}.fq.gz.md5") output.
- Also, I'm interested in a solution which doesn't use `dynamic` because it is deprecated.

```py
rule all:
    input:
         "md5",
         "bams/{sample}.bam",

rule download_files_list:
    output: "md5"
    #shell: "wget {}".format(config["url_files_list"])
    run:
        # For testing instead of downloading:
        content = """
        bfe583337fd68b3  ID_001_1.fq.gz
        1636b6756daa65f  ID_001_2.fq.gz
        0428baf25307249  ID_002_1.fq.gz
        de33d81ba5bfa62  ID_002_2.fq.gz
        """.strip()
        with open(output[0], mode="w") as f:
            print(content, file=f)

rule fastq_md5_files:
    input: "md5"
    output: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz.md5"
    shell: "mkdir -p fastq && awk '{{ print $0 > (\"fastq/\" $2 \".md5\") }}' {input}"

rule download_fastq_and_check_md5:
    input: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz.md5"
    output: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz"
    #shell: "wget {}/{{sample}} && md5sum --check {{input}}".format(config["url_file_prefix"])
    shell: "touch {output}" 

rule align_fastq:
    input: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz"
    output: "bams/{sample}.bam"
    shell: "touch {output}" # aligning task
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen a lot of confusion over how to use [the new `checkpoint` feature](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution). Here is an illustrative example, simplified:

```
shell.prefix('set -vexu pipefail; ')

rule finish:
        input:
                "D/all.txt"

checkpoint A:
        output:
                mydir = directory("A")
        shell: """
                mkdir -p A
                N=$(( $RANDOM % 7 + 1))
                echo "N=$N"
                # Create a number of files. (
                for i in $(seq 1 $N); do
                        echo $i > "A/$i.txt"
                done
        """

rule B:
        output:
                txt = "B/{i}.txt",
        input:
                txt = "A/{i}.txt",
        shell: """
                mkdir -p B
                cp -f {input.txt} {output.txt}
        """

rule C:
        output:
                txt = "C/{i}.txt",
        input:
                txt = "B/{i}.txt",
        shell: """
                mkdir -p C
                cp -f {input.txt} {output.txt}
        """

def gatherForD_fromC_basedOnA(wildcards):
        checkpoint_output = checkpoints.A.get(**wildcards).output.mydir
        # That will raise if not ready.

        ivals = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output,
                        "{i}.txt")).i
        print("ivals={}".format(ivals))
        return expand("C/{i}.txt", i=ivals)

rule D:
        output:
                combined = "D/all.txt",
        input:
                gathered = gatherForD_fromC_basedOnA,
        shell: """
                mkdir -p D
                cat {input.gathered} > {output.combined}
        """
```

Copy to `snakefile` and run it with

```
snakemake --verbose -p
```

- Checkpoint/Rule `A` outputs a random number of files. (You could base those on an "input" section instead, of course.)
- Rules `B` and `C` are parallel rules using standard **snakemake** "wildcards".
- Rule `D` takes an unknown number of inputs, based on an input-generating function.
- Function `gatherForD_fromC_basedOnA` waits for the output of checkpoint-rule `A`, but it *names* the output of rule `C`, which is finally consumed by rule `D`. As a result, **snakemake** knows what `D` will consume (after `A` is done). So it knows what `C` must produce. So it knows what `B` must produce.
- Finally, rule `finish` waits for a specific, known file.

Comment: Stumbled upon this post when trying to understand the checkpoint feature. Thanks, this was the most helpful resource for understanding it.

Comment: @cdun2001: This is kinda what I was looking for, however, if my `rule A` produces the following: `dir/subdir/{i}.txt` instead of `dir/{i}.txt` as in your example and I want to use the `subdir/{i}.txt` in rule B and from there rule C; will the checkpoints resolved automatically?

Comment: @SusheelBusi, In that case ruleB's input would have to be `txt = "A/subdir/{i}.txt"`. Other than that change, it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the list of fastq files and extract from there the list of samples using pure python code before snakemake rules kicks in:

```
def download_files_list(output):
    """Download the list of fastq files and return the list
    of samples
    """
    content = """
    bfe583337fd68b3  ID_001_1.fq.gz
    1636b6756daa65f  ID_001_2.fq.gz
    0428baf25307249  ID_002_1.fq.gz
    de33d81ba5bfa62  ID_002_2.fq.gz
    """.strip()
    with open(output, mode="w") as f:
        print(content, file=f)
    return ['ID_001_1', 'ID_001_2', 'ID_002_1', 'ID_002_2']    

samples= download_files_list("md5")
wildcard_constraints:
    sample= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in samples]),

rule all:
    input:
         expand("bams/{sample}.bam", sample= samples),

rule fastq_md5_files:
    input: "md5"
    output: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz.md5"
    shell: """awk '{{ print $0 > ("fastq/" $2 ".md5") }}' {input}"""

rule download_fastq_and_check_md5:
    input: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz.md5"
    output: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz"
    #shell: "wget {}/{{sample}} && md5sum --check {{input}}".format(config["url_file_prefix"])
    shell: "touch {output}" 

rule align_fastq:
    input: "fastq/{sample}.fq.gz"
    output: "bams/{sample}.bam"
    shell: "touch {output}" # aligning task
```

(I'm curious myself about a more snakemake-ish solution using checkpoints or similar)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a `single workflow` I meant that md5 downloading & reading tasks should be also snakemake rules of the workflow, not separate things (like download using python or ask user to do it, then read file in python code before workflow DAG is defined).

In my case downloading is not a simple operation, it requires authorization, and using external cmdline tools, so I configured a wrapper + have several snakemake rules for that.